# Using href to call a javascript function that creates a link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to write something that will go to the URL that this function creates.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function VLink() {
    var callNumHeading = $("th[class='BItemsHeader']:contains(NO.)");
    Num = $('table[id="B_items"] tbody tr td a').eq($(NumHeading).index()).text();
    var link = "http://someURL/?q="+Num;
    return link;
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = VLink();
});
</script>
```

I need to create code that will go to the link created in the function above.  The closest I've come is this:

```
<a href="javascript:VLink(); ">My Link</a>
```

This code goes to a page that says it has the same URL as the original page, but all that appears on the page is the URL that I want to go to.  The desired destination URL is appearing in the body of the page instead of the address bar.

Comment: Maybe you forgot some hyphens inside the `:contains()` part? `$("th[class='BItemsHeader']:contains('NO.')");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location = VLink();
```

That should redirect the page that is created by VLink().

Comment: Apologies, I was typing my answer as you just posted yours. Good Answer :)

Comment: <a href="javascript:window.location = VLink(); ">My Link</a> worked! Thanks dbenson and Tez!

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect:

```
window.location.href = VLink();
```

As VLink returns a string, setting to `window.location.href` seems most fitting.

window.location is an object which as many other methods.

Regards,